# Git can not clone/pull/push to GitHub repo

Tags: git, github

Note that the proxy is automatic; I tried to set an IP address and a port number but it does not work. Here I tried to show the config file:

```
D:\rms\restaurant-management-system\.git (master -> origin)
λ cat config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = http://github.com/aramali0/restaurant-management-system.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master

D:\rms\restaurant-management-system\.git (master -> origin)
λ git pull
fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree

D:\rms\restaurant-management-system\.git (master -> origin)
λ cd ..

D:\rms\restaurant-management-system (master -> origin)
λ git pull
fatal: unable to access 'http://github.com/aramali0/restaurant-management-system.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com

D:\rms\restaurant-management-system (master -> origin)
λ ping github.com
La requête Ping n’a pas pu trouver l’hôte github.com. Vérifiez le nom et essayez à nouveau.

D:\rms\restaurant-management-system (master -> origin)
```

Comment: "Could not resolve host" looks like you are having DNS problems. Can you browse the web from this machine? If the machine is console only, do `curl google.com` in a temporary folder as a basic connectivity check.

Comment: Your proxy may need authentication.

Comment: I can browse the web I'm talking with you from this machine but when I go to terminal try to ping google.com or github.com it take a time but in the end it does not work , The comande that you suggest : 

curl google.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com

Comment: OK, so it sounds like you have internet access on the desktop of that machine, but no internet access at the console. I wonder if you have a proxy successfully configured in your browser, but not at the console. That is what you need to fix next. See how to set up proxy details on the console (search for "curl proxy windows").

Comment: I sloved the probeme just by unistaling the adapter intel for wifi and it start all the settings from 0 inclduing the DNS and proxy , Thank you @halfer for help

Comment: Great stuff. I see this is the third time you've asked a question on this - please try to ask one question per problem, unless the problem changes significantly.

Comment: Yes you are right , Cause every time I ask quetion some new answers come in that s why I will try to delte the quetions

Comment: Please don't routinely delete your questions - it is not how we do things here. The whole point of Stack Overflow is to convert Q&A into permanent documentation that will be useful to many people in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Posted an answer from the question author, in order to move it to the answer section)*:

I solved the problem just by uninstalling the adapter intel for Wi-Fi and it start all the settings from 0 including the DNS and proxy.

Comment: Thank you this waht helepe me I already try it and it works properly,